# Connection to ArcGIS Server via QGIS fails

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, connection

I am trying to load this map that comes from an ESRI Server in QGIS.

I tried two different ways:

- DATA SOURCE MANAGER / PROTOCOL HTTPS or FILE and then adding the URL. When I do this it fails and appears this message. (INVALID DATA SOURCE
- DATA SOURCE MANAGER / ARCGIS Map SERVER. I add the server connection using the URL. It loads the layer but appears a warning message next to it saying.

Network error: Error transferring https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/ownership/FeatureServer/export?bbox=-13849232.281800,3833711.951200,-12704981.773600,5162403.249100&size=1319,1531&format=jpg&layers=show:0&transparent=true&f=image - server replied: Bad Request

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f73858e200634ca888b19ca8c78e3aed .Maybe I am doing it the wrong way, but everytime I load it, I always get the same error.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry I am new in this and maybe I am making a lot of basic errors. I added the steps I am following.

Comment: Are you trying to get the California land ownership layer from there? How did you get the address you are using? what you were trying to do is get the feature layer as an image, which is not possible

Comment: Yes I am trying to load that layer to qGIS. I am using the URL https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/ownership/FeatureServer that I copied from here https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f73858e200634ca888b19ca8c78e3aed

Comment: Just look at my answer

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to load an *ArcGIS FeatureServer* into QGIS and don't need the export you added.

Simply open the *Data Source Manager* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>):

[image]

Go to the *ArcGIS Feature Server* tab and click on <kbd>New</kbd>:

[image]

In the create new arcgise feature server window, give your layer a name and insert the URL (https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/ownership/FeatureServer)
and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

You can now click <kbd>Connect</kbd> to add the layer through the Data Source Manger or straight from the browser:

[image]

Comment: Something is missing or is in excess near *"the layer your through"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Right you are, fixed it.

Comment: and this method will only list 'public' shared layers. I believe...

Comment: @TheoF unless you add authentication

Comment: @DrorBogin yes agreed. Although for authentication to work you need to generate an ArcGIS token for the layer. I belive you can only generate tokens if you have ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Enterprise.

Comment: that depends a lot on the server version and security, some arcgis servers allow for basic authetication, but this is decided by the server manager.

Answer (score 3):

From the last link you have provided, we can see in the `detail` section that it is a `feature service`, and at the bottom there is the service URL https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/ownership/FeatureServer that also indicates that it is a `feature server`.

In QGIS, you would add an `ArcGIS Feature Server` (not a `map server` as you did) with this service URL